# Cannot Log Into ASP.NET MVC App Using Azure AD/OpenID Connect After HTTP POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, openid-connect

I deployed an ASP.NET MVC app to Azure. It uses Azure AD/OpenID Connect. I can log into and log off the app if I do not perform an HTTP POST, such as update a record.

If I update a record and then log off, I cannot log back in. I see a login loop and then the Microsoft "Pick an account" page with the error "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again."

To log back in, I can either (delete the browser history/cache and then redeploy the app to Azure) or restart the app service.

App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs:

```
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Globalization;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
 using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
 using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
 using Microsoft.Owin;
 using Owin;
    
 namespace InternalAppsWeb
 {
     public partial class Startup
     {
         private static readonly string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
         private static readonly string aADInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
         private static readonly string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
         private static readonly string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
         private static readonly string authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aADInstance, tenantId);
    
         public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
         {
             app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    
             app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    
             app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                 new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                 {
                     ClientId = clientId,
                     Authority = authority,
                     PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                     Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                     {
                         AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                         {
                             context.HandleResponse();
                             context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
                             return Task.FromResult(0);
                         }
                     }
                 }
             );
         }
     }
 }
```

Controllers/AccountController.cs:

```
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
 using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
 using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
    
 namespace InternalAppsWeb.Controllers
 {
     public class AccountController : Controller
     {
         public void SignIn()
         {
             if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
             {
                 HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                     new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                     OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
                 );
             }
         }
    
         public void SignOut()
         {
             HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                 OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                 CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
             );
         }
     }
 }
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
 using System.IdentityModel.Claims;
 using System.Web.Helpers;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using System.Web.Optimization;
 using System.Web.Routing;
 using InternalAppsWeb.Extensions;
    
 namespace InternalAppsWeb
 {
     public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
     {
         protected void Application_Start()
         {
             MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
             ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new CustomModelMetadataProvider();
             AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
             FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
             RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
             BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
             AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
         }
     }
 }
```

Web.config:

```
   <appSettings>
     <add key="ida:ClientId" value="fg4267g4-gc5b-57e1-8968-be31258g2b42" />
     <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" />
     <add key="ida:TenantId" value="eg92d42g-b9d1-5bg4-b293-dg4cdf483125" />
     <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:45471/" />
   </appSettings>
```

Comment: Make sure you place these in order `app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();` and check [this](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/11/infinite-sign-in-loop-between-mvc-application-and-azure-ad/)

Comment: @kavyaSaraboju Thank you for your answer. I first made the following change in the Startup.Auth.cs file: app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager() }); and the issue has been resolved. I can login => make a record update (HTTP Post) => log off => log back in without the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When asp.net application fails to recognize the authenticated request from azure ad , it fails to login and then asks to login again.This is because of issue with  owin/katana  which makes cookies disappear.

- In this case, please make sure the cookie is managed properly .

Ensure the following are in order :

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

and Use Cookie manager which secures cookie data
***Startup.Auth.cs :***

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions 
{ 
    AuthenticationType = "Cookies", 
    CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager() 
});
```

[image]

Referred from : [infinite redirect loop between Azure AD and MVC Asp.net application due to old version of OWIN | (aaddevsup.xyz)](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/11/infinite-sign-in-loop-between-mvc-application-and-azure-ad/)